# Save interactive plotly plot in HTML or another way

Tags: python, plotly

I have built this interactive plot that I would like to save to HTML. This is the code I used to build it.

```
def vis_pcs(M, a, b, label='album', prefix='PC', symbol=None):
    fig = px.scatter(M, prefix + str(a), prefix + str(b), 
                        color=label,
                        hover_name='album',
                        hover_data=['genre', 'song_title'],
                        marginal_x='box',
                        symbol=symbol,
                        height=1000)
    fig.show()
```

I'm unsure how to save it I've used the following lines of code to save it but each throws an error:

```
fig.write_html(data_path+"/genre.html")
```

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_html(fig, file=data_path+"/genre.html", auto_open=True)
```

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= data_path+"/genre.html")
```

Any help would be appreciated as for data to reproduce the graph its difficult to give but its a scatterplot

Comment: What errors are being thrown?

Comment: @DerekO when i dod the first one i get this `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_html'`

when I do the second chunk I get this `The fig parameter must be a dict or Figure.
    Received value of type <class 'NoneType'>: None`

and the last chunk gives me this `The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure`

I guess I'm not understanding why my figure is a nonetype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_html'`, the variable fig is being set to a 'NoneType' object.

Currently your function doesn't return anything, so if you are setting fig using your vis_pcs function, `fig = vis_pcs(...)`, this will set fig to a `NoneType` object. In Python, a local variable is only available inside of a function because of [scope rules](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

To resolve this, you can add a return statement to your function:

```
def vis_pcs(M, a, b, label='album', prefix='PC', symbol=None):
    fig = px.scatter(M, prefix + str(a), prefix + str(b), 
                        color=label,
                        hover_name='album',
                        hover_data=['genre', 'song_title'],
                        marginal_x='box',
                        symbol=symbol,
                        height=1000)

    ## add a return statement
    return fig
```

Then set the variable `fig` to the figure that your function returns:

```
fig = vis_pcs(...)
```

After that you should be able to access the `write_html` attribute for Plotly figures and `fig.write_html(data_path+"/genre.html")` should work.